# All analytic bijections from $\{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z-i|>1\}$ to itself

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to find all analytic bijections from $\{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z-i|>1\}$ to itself. I think the first thing to do is to use the map $z\to1/z$ that takes everything to a punctured disk. However, I am not sure how to proceed. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, it's the map $z\mapsto1/(z-i)$ that you are interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the map $z\mapsto\dfrac1{z-i}$, your problem becomes equivalent to the problem of finding all analytic functions from $D(0,1)\setminus\{0\}$ into itself. By Riemann's theorem on removable singularities, each such function can be extended to an analytic map $f$ from $D(0,1)$ into itself. What can we say about $f(0)$? It turns out that $f(0)$ can only be $0$. In fact:

- we can't have $\bigl|f(0)\bigr|=1$, by the maximum modulus theorem;
- if $f(0)=c$ for some $c\in D(0,1)\setminus\{0\}$, then the equation $f(z)=c$ will have *two* solutions; let $c'\in D(0,1)\setminus\{0\}$ be the other one. By the argument principle, if $\gamma_d\colon[0,2\pi]\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ is defined by $\gamma_d(t)=de^{it}$ ($d\in\bigl(|c'|,1\bigr)$), then$$\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_d}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)-x}\,\mathrm dz$$is equal to $2$ if $x=c$ and it is equal to $1$ otherwise, which is impossible.

Therefore, $f$ is rotation.

Comment: Can we also consider maps that send the origin elsewhere? My initial guess is we can only take rotations of the unit disk

Comment: Not quite - a map from the disk to the disk need not take the punctured disk to itself. You need first a little argument showing that after you remove the singularity the new map fixes the origin, hence is a bijection on the disk - then at the end you need to restrict to maps fixing the origin.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich This is how I would make that argument. Say we had a analytic bijection from the punctured disc to itself. If we make an analytic extension by removing the singularity, the new map is a bijection only if it sends the origin to the origin or to the boundary. If the origin is sent to the interior then the map will no longer be bijective

Comment: @Not_a_topologist Yes, but there's a detail missing. Say $D'$ is the punctured disk, $g:D'\to D'$ is the original map, and $f:D\to D$ is the map with the singularity removed. If $f(0)=a\ne0$ that shows that $f$ is not bijective. So what? How does it follow that $g$ is not bijective? (Hint: Open Mapping Theorem...)

Comment: @Not_a_topologist I also left out a detail: Of course we first rule out the possibility $|f(0)|=1$ by the Maximum Modulus Theorem...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes I was thinking about the open mapping theorem. I will try to prove this and let you know if I have any issues

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I have (tried to) correct my error. I hope that all is well now.